# How to make a simple android quiz app?

Tags: android

The first screen of the app should have 2 buttons, the first button displays "Easy" and the second displays "Hard" - this is where the user is choosing the difficulty level.

If the user pressed on the button that displays "Easy", is gonna have to answer 5 random questions and if he pressed the button that displays "Hard", is gonna have to answer 10 random questions. (Do I need an activity for each question or can i display all the questions randomly using only one activity?).

After the user answers all the questions is gonna see a screen that shows his score and a button that will send him back to menu, also I want to give the user a choice to go back to the quiz and see which questions he answered right or wrong.

Can someone teach me how to make this app?

Comment: watch a tutorial series on android development

Comment: This is not a question.  It is a request for personal tuition ("please teach me ...") and that is beyond the scope of this site.  In future please restrict yourself to on-topic questions as described in the site's Help Centre documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need only one activity for the questions, where they (5 or 10 ques) can be displayed dynamically and after the user has answered all the questions you can start a new activity which will show the result and a button (to go to main menu).
Also give here an option to view all the answered question by starting the same question activity (or new ) and now show all the questions with their correct and user's answer dynamically.